# Add a custom FormView to a RadGrid Edit Item Template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radgrid, formview

I had a `Dropdrowlist` and `FormView` to work hand in hand to edit/update data.

Now I need to add a radGrid and when a user clicks on the row, I need the `FormView` to be populated or I need my existing `FormView` to be populated inside the RadGrid's edit item template.